# GAE: Access blobstore content programmatically?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, blobstore

**My Usecase:** I don't use the blobstore for uploading and downloading files. I use the blobstore to store very large strings my program is creating. With persisting the path where the blob is stored, I can later load the string again (see [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview#Writing_Files_to_the_Blobstore))

**My Question:** Is there an easier way to access the blob content without the need to store the path? BlobstoreService only allows me to directly serve to the HttpServletReponse.

Comment: why not use 'Text' for storing large strings?

Comment: 'Text' can only store 1MB ([see api](http://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities#Properties_and_Value_Types)) and the whole datastore is limited to 1MB ([see api](http://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/overview#Quotas_and_Limits))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to store a BlobKey - there is never a need to store a path (files or not).

To access contents of a blob:

```
BlobstoreService blobStoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
String myString =
   new String(blobStoreService.fetchData(blobKey, 0, BlobstoreService.MAX_BLOB_FETCH_SIZE-1);
```

EDIT:
If you have a very long string, you can use any standard way of reading a byte array into a string by fetching data from a blob in a loop.

Comment: Since the MAX_BLOB_FETCH_SIZE=1015808 ([see api](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/constant-values#com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobstoreService.MAX_BLOB_FETCH_SIZE)), would I have to fetch all byte[]-parts in a loop, connect them and then cast to String?

Comment: No need for a loop. The code I gave will fetch the entire string in one step. There is no penalty for setting the last index larger than the actual string length.

Comment: and if my string is way larger then 1MB?

Comment: Then you can loop through the blob as you suggested in your first comment. You don't need a FileService for this - you are adding an extra, unnecessary step.

Comment: I perfromed a couple of test (~5MB Blobs). Your solution reads them around 20 times faster then a fileservice. THANKS!

`ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
for (int i = 0; i < blobInfo.getSize(); i += BlobstoreService.MAX_BLOB_FETCH_SIZE) {outputStream.write(blobStoreService.fetchData(blobInfo.getBlobKey(), i, i + BlobstoreService.MAX_BLOB_FETCH_SIZE - 1));}
returnValue = outputStream.toString("UTF-8");`

Comment: Any idea how to do this in Python?

Answer (score 0):

I guess when you said "persisting the path where the blob is stored", you mean [`BlobKey`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/blobstore/BlobKey)?

`FileService` allows you to directly access blob data:

```
// Get a file service
FileService fileService = FileServiceFactory.getFileService();

// Get a file backed by blob
AppEngineFile file = fileService.getBlobFile(blobKey)

// get a read channel
FileReadChannel readChannel = fileService.openReadChannel(file, false);

// Since you store a String, I guess you want to read it a such
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(Channels.newReader(readChannel, "UTF8"));
// Do this in loop unitil all data is read
String line = reader.readLine();
```

Comment: There is no need to use FileService in order to fetch a string from a BlobStore. It can be done directly with a BlobstoreService.

Comment: `AppEngineFile file = fileService.getBlobFile(blobKey)` is exactly what I was looking for! Together with `(new BlobInfoFactory()).queryBlobInfos()` it was easy to build a little put/get wrapper around the blobstore. Thanks

Comment: BTW: When I said "persisting the path where the blob is stored", I really mean the path. What I **was** doing is saving with `path = file.getFullPath()` and loading with `AppEngineFile file = new AppEngineFile(path);`.

Comment: This is not the fastest solution (see above)! But just in case somebody needs the code anyway:
`AppEngineFile file = fileService.getBlobFile(blobInfo.getBlobKey());
boolean lock = false;
FileReadChannel readChannel = fileService.openReadChannel(file, lock);
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(Channels.newReader(readChannel, "UTF-8"));
returnValue = bufferedReader.readLine();
bufferedReader.close();
readChannel.close();`